# OpenCV error while reszing new created window is there any other way to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, trackbar

```
cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")
cv2.resize("Trackbars", 640 ,420)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","Trackbars",0,179,empty)
```

I am using this code to create and resize the new window but its showing giving me following error:
what am doing wrong here ?

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two slightly different ways to do this.

I would recommend changing `resize` to `resizeWindow`.
`cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` keeps the correct ratio of an image (if you have one).

> ```
> cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars", cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
> cv2.resizeWindow("Trackbar", 640, 420)
> ```

You could also resize the window in a ratio form instead of a specific pixel - this is if you have the media input as a variable (`image`).

> `cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.4, fy=0.4)`

Comment: how to call this fuction for trackbars ?

Comment: @Spartex I've now updated my question for it to be more relatable.

Comment: @Spartex No worries, did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah it did but i cant ask new questions can you please upvote this question so I will be able to ask again ?

Comment: I see, would it be possible to accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.resize("Trackbars", 640 ,420)`
"Trackbars" is not an numpy array. Add an image here. hence src error. Use cv2.imread to read your image or from another source.
Secondly, 640, 420 should be a tuple (640,420) i.e dimensions.

Comment: Documentation for cv2.namedWindow()
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b